# Error loading operating system on Windows 7 Install USB

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, usb, usb-flash-drive

I created a Windows 7 Install USB the usual way. NTFS partition on pendrive, made it bootable, copyed all files from DVD to the pendrive, test it on my laptop.

It works, at least on my laptop (HP ProBook).

But when i try to use it on another laptop I have, I get this error message:
`error loading operating system

I don't get it, why it worls on some laptop and not on anothers?

UEFI is disabled, it boots from USB first.

Comment: Is the USB a 64-Bit version of Windows and the problem laptop 32-Bit architecture?

Comment: Does that laptop boot up successfully? (not with the USB drive obviously)

Comment: No, the USB has a 64-bit version and both laptops have 64-bit architecture.

Comment: Yes, the laptop boots correctly with Ubuntu. It's new.

Comment: Did you completely wipe the USB flash drive before setting it up as a bootable install drive? Perhaps there is something left over from a previous use of the drive that's causing the problem.

Comment: The thing is that the pendrive was also new, without nothing previously. And yes, I wiped it with gparted to make a ntfs partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a guy that had a same problem, Writing zeros with dd and then reformating solved his problem.

I thought that maybe there was a problem with the partition table that gparted was not able to detect. So I used fdisk to reformat everything. After that it worked flawlessly.

Thank you everyone.